# How to use JobScheduler instead of BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I want to use BroadcastReceiver like this

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.MediaReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I had read [Using the JobScheduler API on Android Lollipop](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-jobscheduler-api-on-android-lollipop--cms-23562),but I still don't know how to do.

Comment: I think you might be confused about the purposes of these two mechanisms. They don't exactly replace one another. Especially not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was your original question, but I came across this because of the deprecation of [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html), which was previously the standard way of listening for an intent and then doing activity that requires a wake lock.

The answer is that you should still use BroadcastReceiver to receive  intents like you've set in the intent-filter.  If you need a wake lock, which you likely don't, then schedule a job from your BroadcastReceiver instead of using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver.